# Select records having max value in column using NHibernate QueryOver

Tags: nhibernate, queryover

Can I do this using QueryOver in NHibernate?

```
   SELECT *
   FROM TABLE_X T1
   WHERE T1.COL1 = (SELECT MAX(COL1) FROM TABLE_X T2 WHERE T1.NAME = T2.NAME)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out these questions to solve your problem:

- [How can I express joining to a grouped subquery using NHibernate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4128686/how-can-i-express-joining-to-a-grouped-subquery-using-nhibernate/6532338#6532338)
- [Selecting on Sub Queries in NHibernate with Critieria API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6541229/selecting-on-sub-queries-in-nhibernate-with-critieria-api/6544864#6544864)